# Getting around sub-query limitation in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this query to re-order items in a MySQL Table

```
Update Content.items SET list_order=list_order+1 Where list_order=
(Select list_order-1 From Content.items where id='41e31kufg');
```

But i get this error:

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'items' for update in FROM clause
```

Heres an example of a dataset before re-ordering

```
rowid    list_order
41e31kufg 1
62g88nfjs 2
99h84mlkd 3
92r63mkvf 4
```

After reordering:

```
rowid    list_order
99h84mlkd 1
92r63mkvf 2
41e31kufg 3
62g88nfjs 4
```

What is the solution for this ?

Comment: Hava a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: Please provide some example like sample data and expected output.

Comment: @genespos i have seen that thread, i am afraid, i cannot tailor that solution to my needs. I am a total sql noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE items 
SET list_order=list_order+1 
WHERE list_order= (
    SELECT (
        SELECT list_order-1 
        FROM (
            SELECT list_order 
            FROM items 
            WHERE id='41e31kufg') AS x))
```

Comment: Thanks, That 'SELECT'ception looks very odd. How will this query perform ? Can it handle high traffic ? Is there an optimized solution for this ?

Comment: @koder every subquery slows but you need to try it because if a query works on a primary key is faster. If this way is too slow you'll need to find a way using JOIN as in the link I gave you

Answer (score 0):

Manage to piece together this solution:

```
Update Content.items SET list_order=list_order+1 Where list_order>= ? and 
list_order < (Select * From (Select list_order From Content.items where id=?) AS lists);
Update Content.items SET list_order=? WHERE id=?;
```